# Impossible to remove proximity alert

Tags: android, notifications, alert, android-pendingintent, proximity

The users have a switch to activate or deactivate proximity alerts.

When the user active this switch, the proximity alert will show in a notification way. With this notification on the action bar, if the user change the switch to "deactivate" mode, the notification disappears. It works ok.

But my problem is this:

I active the alerts, but it not shows anything in that moment because I'm not near of a POI. I've changed my mind and now, I don't want any alert, so I change the switch to "deactivate" mode (any notification has appeared on the action bar).

However, with the switch on the "deactivate" mode, the alert will appear on the action bar when I'm near of a POI, and I don't know why.
I'm using the removeProximityAlert with the value of the pending intent for each POI.

**To activate alerts:**

```
public void activateAlerts() {

    Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor cursor = db.getPois();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        ...
        Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

        String idSubstring = id.substring(7);
        int lastDigitsOfID = Integer.parseInt(idSubstring);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), lastDigitsOfID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        try {
            locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, Utils.RADIOALERTS, -1, pi);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName().toString(), e.toString());
        }
        notifications.add(new NotificationObject(cursor.getString(idIndex), lastDigitsOfID));
    }
    db.addNotifications(notifications);
}
```

**To deactivate alerts:**

```
public void deactivateAlerts() {

    Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor cursor = db.getIdPendingIntents();

    int idPendingIntentIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("id_pendingintent");
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT); 
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                cursor.getInt(idPendingIntentIndex), intent, 0);
        locationManager.removeProximityAlert(pendingIntent);
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

I've read this posts:

[Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761033/android-removing-proximity-alert)

[Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505726/how-to-add-and-remove-multiple-proximity-alerts-in-location-manager)

[Post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471025/android-remove-proximity-alert-after-notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`. This isn't well documented, but it should work if you remove that flag.

When you create a `PendingIntent` with `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, Android doesn't keep track of this `PendingIntent` (as it is only allowed to be used once). In my opinion this is an "optimization" which is actually an Android bug :-(

When you call `removeProximityAlert()` and pass it the `PendingIntent`, the code in that method tries to cancel all proximity alerts that have a **matching** `PendingIntent`. Since Android doesn't keep track of `PendingIntent`s created with `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, the "matching" code never finds your proximity alert so it doesn't cancel it.

Comment: Let me know if this solves your problem and I will add more explanation. I'm not able to do this at the moment.

Comment: I'm testing instead of PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT, with the 0 value. From the work office it seems that works fine (in a while I will to test it in a real situation), but, can you explain me why  FLAG_ONE_SHOT not works correctly? I've no idea =(

Comment: Added an explanation to my answer. It's an Android bug IMHO.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/29780579/769265 the problem there is different but the behaviour of `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` also contributes to confusion in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Is this really the same?

**activate:**

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), lastDigitsOfID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

**deactivate:**

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),cursor.getInt(idPendingIntentIndex), intent, 0);
```

Please check out [intentEquals()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) method and make sure, your intents are equal following the criteria described there.

Comment: Yes, it's the same value... I store the value on a local database (activate), and then I load the values for each POI (cursor of deactivate). I've checked it with logs, and yes, it has the same value.

Comment: I've test the code with the method, and it returns "true" for the intents...  They are the same =(